# nextjs typescript image loader

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextjs-image, cloudflare-pages

I'm building a website with NEXT.js typescript.
I'm a newbie in typescript.

I need to make ImageLoader because cloudflare pages not support default image loader.
but my code is not working and i don't know why.

Loader code:

```
const normalizeSrc = (src: string) => {
  return src.startsWith("/") ? src.slice(1) : src;
};

const cloudflareLoader = ({
  src,
  width,
  quality,
}: {
  src: string;
  width: number;
  quality: number;
}) => {
  const params = [`width=${width}`];
  if (quality) {
    params.push(`quality=${quality}`);
  }

  const paramsString = params.join(".");
  return `/cdn-cgi/images/${paramsString}/${normalizeSrc(src)}`;
};
```

Image code:

```
<Image
  loader={cloudflareLoader}
  src="/images/image-name.png" // image in public/images folder
  height={120}
  width={120}
  alt=""
/>
```

error:

```
Type '({ src, width, quality, }: { src: string; width: number; quality: number; }) => string' is not assignable to type 'ImageLoader'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'p' are incompatible.
    Type 'ImageLoaderProps' is not assignable to type '{ src: string; width: number; quality: number; }'.
      Types of property 'quality' are incompatible.
        Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

what should I do?

I reffered to https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/integration-with-frameworks/

Comment: try typing `quality` as optional: `quality?: number` - this should at least fix the current type error

Answer (score 0):

Importing the type definition from `next/image` will ensure that you are not making up your own types, using the one from next is way safer as you will always know that it's what next expects.

You can do that like this:

```js
import type { ImageLoaderProps } from 'next/image';

export default function imageLoader({ src, width, quality }: ImageLoaderProps) {...}
```

Your code example would become this:

```js
import type { ImageLoaderProps } from 'next/image';

const normalizeSrc = (src: string) => {
  return src.startsWith('/') ? src.slice(1) : src;
};

const cloudflareLoader = ({ src, width, quality }: ImageLoaderProps) => {
  const params = [`width=${width}`];
  if (quality) {
    params.push(`quality=${quality}`);
  }

  const paramsString = params.join('.');
  return `/cdn-cgi/images/${paramsString}/${normalizeSrc(src)}`;
};
```